# Return an array of frames from a video in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, video-processing

I have code to capture the frames of a video. I need to put the first 20 frames in an array.  How can I do that?  Below is the code that I have:

```
filename = 'Wildlife.wmv';
mov = mmreader(filename);

% Output folder
outputFolder = fullfile(cd, 'frames');
if ~exist(outputFolder, 'dir')
   mkdir(outputFolder);
end

%getting no of frames

numberOfFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;
numberOfFramesWritten = 0;

for frame = 1 :20
   thisFrame = read(mov, frame);
   outputBaseFileName = sprintf('%3.3d.bmp', frame);
   outputFullFileName = fullfile(outputFolder, outputBaseFileName);
   imwrite(thisFrame, outputFullFileName, 'bmp');
   progressIndication = sprintf('Wrote frame %4d of %d.', frame,numberOfFrames);
   disp(progressIndication);
   numberOfFramesWritten = numberOfFramesWritten + 1;
end

progressIndication = sprintf('Wrote %d frames to folder "%s"',numberOfFramesWritten,outputFolder);
disp(progressIndication);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place each frame into a 3D array, and return a stacked 3D array.  As such, before your `for` loop, do this:

```
videoFrames = [];
```

Inside your `for` loop, after the `read` statement, do this:

```
videoFrames = cat(3,videoFrames,thisFrame);
```

The above case only covers **grayscale** images.  For colour images, you'll need to create a 4D array, as the third dimension will be colour channels.  In other words, do this:

```
videoFrames = cat(4,videoFrames,thisFrame);
```

To make this colour or grayscale agnostic, you can check to see how many dimensions are returned from the `size` method.  `size` returns an `N x 1` vector that contains the size of each dimension and `N` would be the total number of dimensions.  This would be a 2 element array if it's a 2D array (grayscale) and a 3 element array if it's a 3D array (colour).  As such, you could change the above two statements to a single one such that:

```
videoFrames = cat(numel(size(thisFrame)) + 1, videoFrames, thisFrame);
```

You simply count how many dimensions there are, and add 1 to stack in the next dimension.

---

If you want to access the i<sup>th</sup> frame, you can do:

```
frame = videoFrames(:,:,i); %// Grayscale
frame = videoFrames(:,:,:,i); %// Colour
```

Comment: You can initialize `videoFrames` to save some calculation time. `videoFrames = zeros([size(read(mov, 1)), 20])` and then store frames with `videoFrames(:,:,ii) = thisFrame;` (for grayscale).

Comment: @Yvon - Thank you for the suggestion.  I decided not to pre-allocate as the OP seems to be a new user of MATLAB.  As such, I decided to go for readability and simple modifications to the established code in order to get things running.  Though your suggestion is certainly valid, I decided not to do this for the sake of the OP.